# How can I use lodash succinctly to update a nested array of objects?

Tags: javascript

This below gives me a very weird `arro` such as `[{keys:values},...keys:values]`. Not ideal.

[image]

1. It updates what I want.
2. It also explodes the object and appends it to the bottom.

```
let arro = [
    {
        "name": "aml_kyc",
        "order": 4,
        "title": "Complete KYC/AML",
        "online": true,
        "enabled": true,
        "completed": false,
        "description": "You must pass anti-money laundering checks."
    },
    {
        "name": "payment_video",
        "order": 6,
        "title": "Video Payment",
        "online": false,
        "enabled": true,
        "completed": false,
        "description": "Optional video production and preparation."
    },
    {
        "name": "conference_call",
        "order": 2,
        "title": "Origination Call",
        "online": false,
        "enabled": true,
        "completed": false,
        "description": "Our team will contact you to arrange this."
    },
    {
        "name": "onboarding_public",
        "order": 8,
        "title": "Public Onboarding",
        "online": true,
        "enabled": true,
        "completed": false,
        "description": "Fill in the information memorandum for public fundraising."
    },
    {
        "name": "onboarding_private",
        "order": 7,
        "title": "Private Onboarding",
        "online": true,
        "enabled": true,
        "completed": false,
        "description": "Fill in key questions to complete the application."
    },
    {
        "name": "payment_onboarding",
        "order": 5,
        "title": "Onboarding Payment",
        "online": false,
        "enabled": true,
        "completed": false,
        "description": "Fee to use our platform services."
    },
    {
        "name": "engagement_documents",
        "order": 3,
        "title": "Fee and Equity Agreements",
        "online": false,
        "enabled": true,
        "completed": false,
        "description": "Our team will arrange this with you."
    },
    {
        "name": "essential_information",
        "order": 1,
        "title": "Essential Information",
        "online": true,
        "enabled": true,
        "completed": true,
        "description": "Executive summary and basic company information."
    }
];

console.log(_.merge(_.set(_.find(arro, {name: "aml_kyc"}), 'online', 1234)), arro);
```

Comment: Just trying to get the `online` key to have a value of `1234` in the first item i.e. `aml_kyc`

Comment: Since find is by reference, you don't need to merge.  `_.find(arro, {name: "aml_kyc"}).online = 1234` - shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: What if I want to update the entire object or one or more keys. See screenshot by the way.

Comment: In that case, I'd filter to get the object, change, and then push back.

Comment: How would I go about that? The merge is the problem. Its doing 2 things.

Comment: Do you need to keep the position in order?

Comment: Okay I guess I understand better now. So `_.find()` mutates the original array. Any order.